# textbox not reading scanned in input

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, newline, barcode

I am developing an app which scans a barcode and inputs the data in a textbox on a C# WPF application. The problem is that when I scan in my information, newlines disappear.  I have scanned the same input into notepad and notepad++, and they seem to show the newlines, but it's not appearing in the textbox. I've even made the textbox multi-lined, and that didn't work.

I think the textbox is filtering out my characters. Is there any way I can make it so that the textbox doesn't do this?

## Desired Output

```C#
the
cow
jumped
over
the
moon
```

## Actual Output

```c#
thecowjumpedoverthemoon
```

This is what I have for my text box code

```c#
<TextBox x:Name="textbox_txt" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" Margin="56,138,239.4,66.8" Background="White" AllowDrop="True" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scanned text might use Unix-style new line character `\n` whereas windows uses `\r\n`. Try:

```
var text = textbox_txt.Text.Replace("\n", "\r\n");
```

or alternatively:

```
var text = textbox_txt.Text.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: `textbox_txt.Text = "foo\nbar\rbaz";` results in two newlines. Just tested that.

Comment: tried both inputs but still getting the same result.  Like I said it is as if the tex tbox is omitting certain characters as the scanner inputs them into the text box

Comment: Could explain how do you scan bar codes? To make your tests, did you scan the bar codes with some sort of external software and then copy and pasted the results into notepad, notepad++, textbox etc?

Comment: the scanner is a simple keyboard type barcode, meaning it is as if you are using the keyboard.  I am entering the information straight into a text box on my wpf app, but the issue is that it is not recognizing the \n as a character.  it only enters a newline when \r\n is entered.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `string` you are assigning to your `TextBox` is not `\n` separated.
Try using `SringBuilder`

```
StringBuild sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("the");
sb.AppendLine("cow");
sb.AppendLine("jumped");
sb.AppendLine("over");
sb.AppendLine("the");
sb.AppendLine("moon");
textbox_txt.Text = sb.Tostring();
```

I just carried out your example, in your usecase you have to just append your scan code to `sb`.